# Vuetify / Vue (2) data table not sorting / paginating upon new bound prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuetify.js, vuex

Keeping the table as basic as possible to figure this out. I am struggling to learn how to create server side sorting/pagination to function in vuetify. When I add the :options or :server-items-length bind the table no longer sorts or paginates.

Without either of those, I get a default listing of 10 items per row - and the sorting all works perfectly fine as well the pagination. However, parameters in the api require a page item count thus forcing a hardcoded number or using the :options bind. If i just place a hard coded number things work fine, but when I bind I get proper items per page but no sorting and pagination.

Very simple data table:

```
             <v-data-table
           :items="ItemResults.items" 
           :headers="TableData.TableHeaders" 
           :loading="TableData.isLoading" 
       >
         </v-data-table>    

    

//Base data returns, with headers and options as well the array that items are stored in.

    

   data() {
         return {
             ItemResults:[],
             TableData: {
                 isLoading: true,
                 TableHeaders: [
          
                     { value: "title", text: "Title" },
                     { value: 'artist', text: 'Artist' },
                     { value: 'upc', text: 'UPC' },
                     { value: "retailPrice", text: "Price/Quantity"},
                 ],
             },
             options: 
             {
                page: 1, 
                itemsPerPage: 15
            },
         }
     },    

    

//Then last, my async method to grab the data from the api, and place it in the itemresults array.

             
    async getProducts(){
             this.TableData.isLoading = true;
             const { page, itemsPerPage } = this.options;
             var temp = await this.$axios.get(`Inventory/InventoryListing_inStock/1/${page}/${itemsPerPage}`);
             this.ItemResults = temp.data;
             this.TableData.isLoading = false;
             return this.ItemResults;
         },
```

I have tried following [Vuetify Pagination and sort serverside guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort), but I'm not sure where they are recommending to make the axios call.

The lead backend dev is working on setting a sorting function up in the api for me to call paramaters to as well - Im not sure how that will function along side.

### but I dont know how to have this controlled by vuetify eithier, or the best practice here.

EDIT:
I've synced the following:

```
           :options.sync="options"
           :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
           :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
```

but i think I dont need to sync the last two. My options:

```
             options: 
             {
                page: 1, 
                itemsPerPage: 15,
                sortBy: ['title'],
                sortDesc: [false]
            },
```

and in my data I put the array for sort by and sort desc

```
            sortBy: [
                'title', 'artist', 'upc', 'retailPrice'
            ],
            sortDesc:[true, false],
```

pagination is now working, and sort ascending is now working, but when I click to descend the header I get an error that the last two params are empty on update to / / instead of /sortBy/sortDesc result. So its not listing the values on changes.

Comment: You need to specify a sort order for every column you sort by, so `sortBy` and `sortDesc` has to be the same length. `sortBy: ['title', 'artist', 'upc'], and sortDesc:[true, false, true]`, means you want to sort by title descending, artist ascending and upc descending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When your component mounts, you need to fetch the total number of items available on the server and the first page of data, and set these as `:items` and `:server-items-length`. The latter will (as you observed) disable paging and sorting, as your server will take care of it, and it is used to calculate the total number of pages given a selected page size.
2. Now you need to know when to reload data. For this, you either bind `options` to the `v-data-table` with two-way binding (`.sync`) and set a watcher on it, or you listen to the `update:options` event. And whenever options change, you fetch the selected data from the server.

That's basically all it takes.

In your template:

```
       <v-data-table
           :items="items" 
           :headers="headers" 
           :loading="true"
           :server-items-length="numberOfItemsOnServer"
           @update:options="options => loadPage(options)"
       />
```

In your component:

```
methods: {
  async loadPage(options){
    this.items = [] // if you want to show DataTable's loading-text
    this.items = await fetch('yourUrl' + new URLSearchParams({
      // build url params from the options object
      offset: (options.page - 1) * options.itemsPerPage,
      limit: options.itemsPerPage,
      orderBy: options.sortBy.map((sb,ix) => [sb, options.sortDesc[ix] ? 'desc' : 'asc'])
    }))
  }
}
```

Comment: ty for the response! Im a little confused. You mentioned use .sync, but I dont see that anywhere? Is the @update a .sync ?

I did some digging and made some changes:
           :options.sync="options"
with a watcher:

     watch: {
        options: {
            handler (){
                this.getProducts()
            },
            deep: true
        }
     },

this works! I get pagination, but I can only sort ascending on items. I get an error.

My options:

Comment: options: 
             {
                page: 1, 
                itemsPerPage: 15,
                sortBy: ['title'],
                sortDesc: [false]
            },

the error is that the API doesnt recognize the change when I click on something. so I assume the array options isnt the correct response to the api.  I will update the post with more details.

Comment: I updated my changes with current results. I didnt understand the reason for offset, and limit. Could you elaborate on those a bit? Sorry, just starting out here.

Comment: @RyanRockwell Oh, `@options.sync=options` means that the v-data-table can update the `options` variable by emitting an `update:options` event. So instead of watching `options`,  you can also listen to the `update:options` event (unless options is modified from somewhere else, too). Offset and limit is how you specify a data a page from a database, so if your service expects a database-centered input format (in contrast to a page-based format), this is how you would transform options. But it is just a random example, point is that you have to tell your service which page to get.,

Comment: Im sorry -  @options.sync=options is correct for the above, or @update:options="options" ?

Comment: `@options.sync` does not exist. `:options.sync=options` is two-way binding, it is shorthand for `:options="options" @update:options="$event => options = $event"`, And since the update is just a regular event, you can set any listener to it, i.e. `@update:options="options => handler(options)". Looking at the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) might be more helpful.

Comment: fixed this issue. will updat,e ty!